# How to retrieve values from HTML table to post to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Lets say I have a table where the id is unique for each input field with a count at the back, how do i retrieve the input values from the table and post them to PHP

```
<table id="tableA">
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
      <tr>
          <td> <input id="a$i" /> </td>
          <td> <input id="b$i" /> </td>
          <td> <input id="c$i" /> </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't put values to ID, there is special attribute for value for inputs. To retieve values just use jquery like $("#yourid").val(), and then send it via ajax method of jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create a `<from method ="post">` before loop and end it after loop `</form>`

2.Now create form fields with `name` attribute as an array like :

```
<table id="tableA">
<form action="your_php_page.php" method="POST">
    <?php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){?>
      <tr>
          <td> <input name="data[a][$i]" /> </td>
          <td> <input name="data[b][$i]" /> </td>
          <td> <input name="data[c][$i]" /> </td>
      </tr>
     <?php }?>
</form>
</table>
```

3.After post you will get data like this

```
data = array(

    'a' =>array(
        0=>'value0',
        1=>'value1'
    ),
    'b' =>array(
        0=>'value0',
        1=>'value1'
    ),
    'c' =>array(
        0=>'value0',
        1=>'value1'
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, can i know how to get the array from the table in the 3rd step?

Comment: @Alexander  when you will submit form. on the next page(page URL you have given in form `action`) you need to check `$_POST`. and you will get all data.

Answer (score 1):

Put your table inside a form tag

```
<form action="your_php_page.php" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

And instead of **id** use **name** property.

And then access values in php with $_POST['**name**'].